# How can I store the output of "top" instead of having it print to the terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

If you type into console:

```
top
```

you get the whole terminal screen filled with the application.

But what I'm interested in is the output of `top` stored into a variable instead of `top` taking display of my console.

How to use `top` in `sh` or `bash` shell to get the `top` app print stored into a variable that later can be echoed?

I don't need to keep the `top` alive after getting its output, it may be called again if I need updated values;.

Comment: Can I ask why do you need to do that?

Comment: I have a script that gives me stats of my app and would like also to put some stats from top as well. The script I have is periodically called to generate stats (approx once per second) but is missing the data from the `top`. If I had the output from the `top` as a string then I would be able to add the data by another `echo "$top_stat";`.

Comment: Some versions of `top` have a "batch mode" flag, `-b`, for example the one described [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html).

Comment: As an alternative, you could gather the same information using `uptime`, `free` and `ps`.

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu thank you for the alternatives, I'll give them a try for sure.

Comment: `top` is not standardized by POSIX, so every OS vendor's implementation is different. Anyhow, it's liable to contain terminal control characters, and trying to parse output built for humans programatically is both error-prone and fragile (a new version of the program can break it without warning; even just a new version of the `ncurses` library or a different `TERM` can do that).

Comment: ...much better to use tools and interfaces that were developed with programmatic use in mind. `top` gets its data out of `/proc`; why don't you just go straight to the source yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some versions of `top` have a [batch mode](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html#1._COMMAND-LINE_Options), which can be enabled with `top -b`. It'll run for the number of iterations set with `-n`, or until killed.

For example, to get a snapshop of the current top five most CPU intensive processes, you'd use

```
top -b -n 1 -o +%CPU | head -n 5 > snapshot
```